# Point Estimates Using C.I.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

0.680 < p < 0.800

What is the point estimate for p, and the margin of error from which the C.I. was formed?

I am confused as to what "p̂" and "E" are equal to. Normally, I would use the population and samples sizes, but this information is not available.

Comment: Also, there are several ways of forming a CI for a proportion: Clopper-Pearson, Agresti-Coulli, Wilson Score Interval, Wald interval, Normal Approximation, to name a few.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329456/point-estimate-margin-of-error

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $[0.680, 0.800]$ is meant to be a symmetrical, 95% confidence interval, then:

$\hat{p} - 1.96\hat{\sigma}_p=0.680 \\
\hat{p} + 1.96\hat{\sigma}_p=0.800$

Hence, by solving simultaneously, I get $\hat{p} = 0.740$ and $\hat{\sigma}_p = 0.0306$.

Comment: Do you think the "standard deviation" and "margin of error" mean the same thing?

Comment: No, margin of error is well defined in its own right, but it can be derived from the standard deviation quite easily (or from the confidence interval directly).